# What´s the dimension of a Sierpinski fractal?

Tags: fractals

I know the dimension of a Koch snowflake (log4/log3), but what numbers do I have to put in to obtain the dimension of a Sierpinski fractal?

Comment: As stated on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle#Properties), $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$.

Comment: Do you mean the Sierpinski _carpet_ or the Sierpinski _triangle_?

Comment: The triangle is the one I mean (I didn´t know there was a carpet too).

Comment: It's basically the same thing, only instead of removing the middle fourth of a triangle, and then repeat on the three remaining small triangles, you remove the middle ninth of a square, and repeat on the eight remaining small squares.